# Why isn't my Jquery & Javascript graph appearing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have all the scripts src'd in the footer and the CSS linked in the header. I have then got the javascript in the page with the div id "chart1" but the actual graph is not appearing and I have no idea why. Please can you enlighten me. Thanks

The place I'm wanting the graph to appear is here.

http://britishlifeinsurance.com/user/leads.php

I'm using the http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php framework.

The scripts I have a initialised are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd first fix the markup of your page. Elements aren't properly closed (your page ends with a `</div>`, while most pages on the net are closed with `</html>`) and instead of a closing `</script>` tag you have a opening `<script>` tag at the end of your plot js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using different js file for JQ plot library:
http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js

- jqPlot
- Pure JavaScript plotting plugin using jQuery
  *
- **Version: 1.0.0b2_r792**

and your is:
http://britishlifeinsurance.com/js/jquery.flot.min.js

/* Javascript plotting library for jQuery, **v. 0.7.**
 *
 * Released under the MIT license by IOLA, December 2007.
 *
 */

Just guessing...

Comment: Also your html structure is not well defined. I have put a breakpoint on 452 line and the code is not executed. Try to fix that first, maybe put some alert box...

Comment: I have added the scripts I have initialised and they are the same as they told me to use in the documentation. Have a look, I have added them to the question.

Comment: Now, add <html> bellow <!DOCTYPE html> and </html> at the end of the file. Your html structure is totally wrong. You MUST fix it before trying to catch js error. (maybe remove that <lang="en"> tag)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/47gbal - here you can see that scripts and meta tags are not shown correctly. Also head tag is empty.